# Why a JSON file couldn't load completely to dynamodb?

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to load a json file to dynamo db in AWS amazon, the JSON file has about 20K rows, but only 80 rows was uploaded successfully to dynamodb, any idea about this?

The following is the lambda uploading code:

```
import boto3
import json
s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
dynamodb1 = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # TODO implement
    bucket = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
    json_file_name = event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key']
    json_object = s3_client.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=json_file_name)
    jsonFileReader = json_object['Body'].read()
    jsonDict = json.loads(jsonFileReader)
    table1 = dynamodb1.Table('table88')
    for record in jsonDict:
        table1.put_item(Item=record)
    return 'Hello from Lambda'
```

Comment: You need to debug your code. How many items are in the dict? Is that number what you expected it to be? Was put_item called the correct number of times? Did every call succeed? Does every item have a unique key, or are there duplicates?

Comment: Number of items are correct, the problem was in the request timeout, i increased it and everything worked well, Anyway Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try increasing the lambda execution timeout value? May be 20k rows need more time to be processed then specified execution timeout.